# Event in a tkinter class, function name not defined

Tags: python, events, tkinter

As I try to make a mini calculator using a Tkinter class, the interpreter returns the "NameError: name 'evaluate' is not defined" error code. I've also tried to define my function evaluate before the "def init" but it still doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.entree = Entry(self)
        self.chaine = Label(self)

        self.entree.bind("<Return>", evaluate)

        self.entree.pack()
        self.chaine.pack()

    def evaluate(self, event):
        self.chaine.configure(text="Result = " + str(eval(self.entree.get())))

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Since it's a class method, you should use `self.evaluate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evaluate` is a method *inside* your `App` class. The method is accessible anywhere inside the class using its `self` member. `self` is the initial class object itself and you cannot access anything(methods, variables etc..) inside the class *without* this member. Therefore, you should use:

```
#<---code---->
self.entree.bind("<Return>", self.evaluate)
#<---code---->
```